# Point struct refuses to be created

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, point

This should be simple enough. Here's my *one* line of code that's giving me trouble:

```
Point tp3 = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
```

And yet if I break directly after that and type "tp3" into the Immediate window, I get "The name 'tp3' does not exist in the current context." What the heck is going on? I have much more code in this project than just that one line, but I'm not sure what could be affecting it. I'm literally breaking on the line directly after this one, and tp3 is nowhere to be seen. If I hover over tp3 while in break mode, I get nothing there either.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Why isn't C# letting me creating a Point??

Edit: I am using the System.Windows.Point struct, and I discovered that I was actually running in Release mode when I meant to be in Debug. Which, of course, was the issue, since tp3 was being garbage collected. Thanks everyone for the quick and accurate responses! I was about to pull my brains out. Yes, my brains.

Edit #2: Actually, as Maupertuis pointed out (pun completely intended), since Point is a struct it isn't be garbaged collected, instead the compiler isn't even allocating space for it in the first place since it isn't used. Thanks Maupertuis!

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: Which `Point` are you talking about? The `System.Drawing.Point` struct wouldn't even compile. Are you using a debug or release build? The `Point` a class or a struct?

Comment: Try using `tp3`, then you'll see if it's really there. You're using the debugger instead, so you're seeing what the debugger wants to show you.

Comment: No, it's not garbage collected. Rather in release mode, the compiler is clever enough to optimize the stack, and doesn't allocate the variable, as you won't use it.

Comment: Even if you use it, it still might not be allocated on the stack.  These small structs easily fit in CPU registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If tp3 is no longer used it will be classed as Out Of Scope and subject to Garbage Collection.

Try adding something like `Point tempP = tp3;` after your line, you should be able to see it then.

Comment: Point being a struct, tp3 is living in the stack and not in the heap. Therefore, Garbage Collection doesn't apply to it. ^_^

Comment: So it does, I forgot that. The Power of Suggestion of the in title "Point *object* refuses..." made me think of objects.

Comment: Changed the title. I was wary of saying "Point struct" because I thought people would think I was trying to define a new struct called Point, rather than an instance (or whatever you call it) of it. In C#, under the hood, are structs implemented as objects anyway? Just curious.

Comment: @MAupertuis - Correct about tp3. Not correct about structs. - a struct variable declared within a method will always be on the stack, whereas a struct variable which is an instance field of a class will be on the heap.- http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html

Comment: I'd have said, "Point instance", as for your other question see Maupertuis's answer.

Comment: @Rith Melton - Correct. I didn't speak about it as in this case, the struct is clearly a method variable. If a struct is a field, it's in the heap if it's contained in something which is in the heap (a class instance for exemple) and it's in the stack if it's in something which live on the stack (a struct declared as a method variable ^^)

Answer (score 2):

If the Optimize Code checkbox is checked in the project properties, it will essentially set a local object to null after its last use so that it can be garbage collected.  Also, if the variable is not used anywhere, it will not actually be allocated.

Doesn't directly depend on the Debug or Release mode, but Debug mode defaults to unchecked (not optimized) and Release defaults to checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing floating point arguments to an integer constructor.

Try instancing a PointF instead:

```
PointF tp3 = new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Even better, since PointF is a structure just use:

```
PointF tp3 = PointF.Empty;
```

Comment: I wish more people would use the null objects. Its clearer and more expressive.